# Set theory: Terminology question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I have some numbers $(a, b)$ which can take any values subject to certain inequalities

$$a + b \geq s_1$$
$$a \geq s_2$$
$$b \geq s_3$$

What is the correct way to describe the set of all valid $(a, b)$? Is it the convex hull of $(a, b)$ satisfying the inequalities or is there some other way to describe this set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convex hull language could be used, but not the way you are using it.

First, the set of all valid $(a,b)$ is simply the *SET* of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ satisfying the inequalities. The set builder notation for this set is described in the other answer.

If you want to formulate this set in geometric language, then you want to think of $(a,b)$ as an ordered pair representing a point in the Cartesian coordinate plane. You can then graph the line $a+b=s_1$ and then use one color to shade in the portion of the plane to the upper-right of that line to represent the inequality $a+b \ge s_1$. Then graph the line $a=s_2$ and use a second color to shade in the portion of the plane to the right of that line to represent the inequality $a \ge s_2$. Finally graph the line $b=s_3$ and use a third color to shade in the portion of the plane above that line to represent the inequality $b \ge s_3$. The portion of the plane with all three colors shaded is then a picture of the SET of all points $(a,b)$ satisfying those inequalities.

You could then describe this set as the convex hull of the union of the two rays and the line segment that form the boundary of the triply shaded region.

Answer (score 1):

It may differ from style to style. I would write something like this:
$$D_f = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb{R} : a+b \geq s_1 \wedge a \geq s_2 \wedge b \geq s_3\}$$

where $s_1, s_2, s_3 \in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Is convex hull of $(a,b)$ satisfying the inequalities correct too?